# Is it correct? $\tan x + \cot x \ge 2$ proof

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

The question is to prove $\tan x + \cot x \ge 2$ when $x$ is an acute angel.

This is what I did

$$\begin{align}
\tan x + \cot x &\ge 2\\
\frac{1}{\sin x \cos x} &\ge 2\\
\left(\frac{1}{\sin x \cos x}\right) - 2 &\ge 0\\
\left(\frac{1 - 2\sin x \cos x}{\sin x \cos x}\right) &\ge 0\\
\left(\frac{(\sin x - \cos x)^2}{\sin x \cos x}\right) &\ge 0\\
\left(\frac{(\sin x - \cos x)^2}{\sin x \cos x}\right) &\ge 0\\
\end{align}$$

Both nominator and denominator will never be negative because nominator is powered to two and cosx & sinx are positive when angel is acute.

Is it correct? Is there another way to solve?

Comment: The last step is wrong, as actually $\sin x=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}$. But at the same time, it is useless, as both $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are positive for an acute angle.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You are right somehow. At first I thought like you but I had doubt because I wasn&#39;t sure if an angel like -45 degree is acute or not so I use square to make the solution right even if a negative angel were acute

Comment: @YvesDaoust edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Nice Work**

Just don't start by assuming the equality or inequality

---

> *Indeed there is another way, There's an elementary way*

**Since we are only concerned about acute angles**

$$\left(a-\frac1a\right)^2\ge0$$

$$a^2-2+\frac1{a^2}\ge0$$
$$a^2+\frac1{a^2}\ge2$$

put $a^2=\tan x$

$$\tan x+\frac1{\tan x}\ge2$$

$$\tan x+\cot x\ge2$$

$\text{Game Over!}$

Comment: This is problematic. What happens when $\tan x < 0$?

Comment: When the angle is acute, sine, cosine, and tangent are all positive.

Comment: Ah, I just saw the acute angle condition.

Comment: I've learnt not to be hasty!

Comment: In retrospect my comment is idiotic, but that's how we learn.

Answer (score 6):

using the lemma $$t+\frac{1}{t}\geq 2$$ for $t>0$  we get the inequality $$\tan(x)+\frac{1}{\tan(x)}\geq 2$$
your way is also ok.

Answer (score 6):

We already have that

$$\tan x + \cot x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} + \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} = \frac{\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x}{\sin x \cos x} = \frac{1}{\sin x \cos x}$$

If $x$ is an acute angle strictly between $0$ and $\pi/2$, then $\sin x \cos x > 0$. Hence $\tan x + \cot x \geq 2$ if and only if $$1 \geq 2\sin x \cos x \ \ \ \ \  \text{  or alternatively }  \ \ \ \ \ \  \sin(2x) \leq 1$$
and this last result is true because $\sin\theta \leq 1$ for all angles $\theta$.

---

In other words, you almost had it. In your second line, you just had to realize that $$2\sin x \cos x$$ could be written as $\sin 2x$ and then bounded above by $1$.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: I don't either, it's an interesting approach in that it only uses trigonometric identities.

Comment: I don't given you a downvote, but I think the reason for downvote is that you don't prove $\sin x \cos x \le \frac {1}{2}$.. I know this is true as well as i know its proof, but you should mention the proof of that.

Comment: Downvote because about all this was already stated in the OP .

Comment: @YvesDaoust *What* was already stated in the OP?

Answer (score 4):

Since $x$ is an acute angle, $\cot x$ and $\tan x$ are positive.

Therefore, by A.M.-G.M. inequality,

$\frac {\tan x + \cot x}{2} \ge \sqrt{\tan x \times \cot x}$

Now, $\tan x \times \cot x = 1$ (by definition)

Therefore we obtain,

$\tan x + \cot x \ge 2 \sqrt{1}$

And so, $\tan x + \cot x \ge 2 $

Proof complete.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy...

$\tan x + \cot x$
= $\tan x + \cot x - 2 \sqrt {\tan x \cot x} + 2 \sqrt{\tan x \cot x}$ 
=$(\sqrt {\tan x} -\sqrt {\cot x})^2+ 2$   [because $\tan x \cot x =1$]

Since square of any number is greater than or equal to zero, we can write, 
$(\sqrt {\tan x} -\sqrt {\cot x})^2 \ge 0$ 
So, $(\sqrt {\tan x} -\sqrt {\cot x})^2 + 2 \ge 2$
But, $(\sqrt {\tan x} -\sqrt {\cot x})^2 + 2 = \tan x + \cot x$ 
So, $\tan x + \cot x \ge 2$

NOTE : We want any square number to make this problem easier, this is a standard technique for proving most of inequalities in mathematics, therefore we have added and subtract $2 \sqrt{\tan x \cot x}$  in the main expression to make the expression perfect square.

Comment: Yes this is quite easy, because that is a standard technique in mathematics, which I have added in the NOTE... and sorry for writing two times "It is quite easy".. it was by mistake. I 've edited this post. Though One should remember that there is nothing like easy and hard in mathematics. Mathematics is just beautiful for finding some techniques.

Comment: What you mean??

Comment: hmm.. that's easier than this for a good explanation.Well done. But critically both are same, isn't?

Answer (score 1):

Let $ y = \tan x + \cot x $.

Then $ y' = \sec^{2} x - \csc^{2} x $.

So when $ y' = 0 $, $ x = \pi/4 $, for $x$ acute.

You can prove this is a minimum by considering $ y' $ for $ x = \pi/6 $ and $ x = \pi/3 $.

Thus $ y_{min} = \tan \pi/4 + \cot \pi/4 = 1 + 1 = 2.$

Answer (score -1):

Even if your implications are correct, your logic is flawed.

Logically, what you have done is similar to

$$\begin{align}
+1&=-1
\\ \Rightarrow (+1)^2&=(-1)^2
\\ \Rightarrow 1&=1.
\end{align}$$
Now $1=1$ so $+1=-1$ must be true also.

Deriving a true statement says nothing about the truth of the hypothesis.

Comment: Are you sure? It works backward

Comment: If it works backwards then it should be done backwards. The logic is flawed the way you have written it. You can't start by assuming what you want to prove. It is the equivalent of starting a trial defence with "Assume the defendant is guilty..."

Comment: @omidh Note none of the other answers start with what you want to prove.

Comment: But my textbook is telling me that I can

Comment: So $+1=-1\Rightarrow 1=1$ so $+1=-1$? Run it backwards and see can you derived $+1=-1$ from $1=1$? Run yours backwards to make it logically sound.

Comment: @omidh Just Proceed with one side of (in)equality and then prove that it is equal to ( lesser or greater than )the other side.

Comment: Though the point you say is valid, but I think this could have been mentioned as a comment rather than an answer. Now, I want to upvote this, but I won't since it's not an answer.

Comment: The question was "Is it correct?". No is the answer and here I explain why.

Answer (score -1):

Notice that $\tan x\times \cot\ x=1$, and
according to the inequality of means we get $$\tan x+\cot x \geqslant 2\sqrt{\tan x\times \cot x}=2$$
which is what we wanted.